# Drupal custom query with localization (How to get user language)

Tags: drupal, localization, translation, drupal-blocks

I have a block that querys the database for a node, however the node can be translated to english/spanish/...

Is there a way to get the user's selected language so I can update the query to something like "AND node.language = 'x'" (en/sp/..)?

```
<?php
$args = explode("/",$_GET['q']);
$result = db_query("
SELECT node_revisions.body AS body FROM 
{node} AS node
INNER JOIN {node_revisions} AS node_revisions ON node.vid = node_revisions.vid
INNER JOIN {term_node} AS term_node ON term_node.nid = node.nid
INNER JOIN {term_data} AS term_data ON term_data.tid = term_node.tid
WHERE term_data.name = '".$args[1]."' AND node.type = 'country_page'
LIMIT 1
", $user->uid);
while($row = db_fetch_object($result)){
  echo($row->body);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can get the user's current language in Drupal with this:

`global $language;`

$lang_name = $language->language;

That should work in both Drupal 6 and Drupal 7.

Reference:
[Drupal API docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--globals.php/global/language/6)